# $scope variables not loading on mvc view, no errors displayed either

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to set up an angular-approached MVC site to show my new boss some benefits of using it - with irony that I got stuck now.

The issue is that interpolating variables onto my view does nothing - it remains clear. I'm running in an MVC 4 environment, and sofar, just binding a `ng-model` on a textbox worked, but getting a value from a controller on-load doesn't

the javascript:

```
var UpdateCataloguesController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello Wurld!";
}

UpdateCataloguesController.$inject = ["$scope"];

asdf.controller('updateCatalogues', UpdateCataloguesController);
```

The html (the `<body>` tag has `ng-app="asdf"` on it, so omitting it here)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="helloAngular" ng-strict-di /> 
<h1>{{helloAngular}} -- THIS WORKS</h1>


<p ng-controller="updateCatalogues">
    <div>{{message}} -- NOTHING BOUND HERE~</div>
</p>
```

Why isn't `{{message}}` interpolating onto my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a block element inside an inline element which doesn't work.

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="updateCatalogues">
    <p>{{message}} -- NOTHING BOUND HERE~</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am going to cry. Don't blame me. it's almost 2am here :C That was the issue. well spotted. and thanks.